# Show SnackBar / Toast above FAB in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How do I show the SnackBar above a FAB/FloatingActionButton?

[image: Snackbar along bottom by default]

Answer (score 0):

#### Add

`behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating`

to the SnackBar.

```
      final snackbar = SnackBar(
        content: Text('Contents saved to disk'),
        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating, // <== Added
      );
```

[image]